# Are Files On Ubuntu One Secure?

Tags: ubuntu-one

are my files stored in Ubuntu One secure from the American intelligence agency (*NSA*)?
In which country are they stored?
Is it better than using Dropbox or any other popular cloud?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score -1):

[This link says they are.](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2013/06/12/how-to-get-out-of-prism-and-avoid-nsa-spying/)

> If you need to use cloud storage, you can do away with Google Drive and Dropbox, and instead use a service like Kim Dotcom’s [Mega](http://mega.co.nz), [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com), or Sparkleshare.